# Is there a function in c# which returns date&time when given GMT values(-12 to -1 and 1 to 12)?

Tags: c#, datetime, gmt

Is there a function in c# which returns date&time when given GMT values(-12 to -1 and 1 to 12)?

**EDIT:**

I have a Dropdownlistbox which contains all GMT values.. Now i want to display date&time of a selected GMT value....

Comment: No love for the Rawaki Islands?

Comment: You might want to give a bit more detail on what you're trying to accomplish.  You might be able to do what yo need with a `DateTimeOffset` structure: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.aspx

Comment: If you don't have +13 or +14, you don't have *all* the timezones there. Not to mention all the nations with half-hour time differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GMT is Greenwich Mean Time, right?   Or better known as UTC?

I think you're referring to UTC *offset*.

In other words, given an offset from GMT, what is the time in that spot?

I think it is

```
DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.UtcNow + new Timespan(offsetHours,0,0),
                     DateTimeKind.LocalTime);
```

except, that's not really true, because the "kind" of that DateTime will be Local, meaning *wherever the computer is right now*. What you really want is a DateTimeKind with a particular timezone.

**Addendum**

Also see the TzTimeZone class that is included in the
PublicDomain project on Codeplex: http://www.codeplex.com/publicdomain.

The System.TimeZone as included in .NET 2.0 does not permit an
application to instantiate a TimeZone object given a shorthand name of
the timezone, or a UTC offset.  Instead, the System.TimeZone class
"knows" about the local timezone but doesn't do much else.  This makes
it difficult to take an arbitrary time (say, 3:13pm, October 4th 2006,
in Los Angeles) and format it for display in an arbitrary other timezone
(say, Paris).

The TzTimeZone class provides a model for a number of different
timezones, including their offsets from UTC and the rules they apply for
daylight savings time.

With this new set of classes, it is possible to instantiate a timezone
from a well-known set of named instances.  It is also easy to format a
time value w.r.t. any arbitrary (named) timezone. In particular, it is
easy to take a time like (3:13pm October 4th 2006, in Los Angeles) and
format it for display in Paris.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```
var d = System.DateTime.Now().ToUniversalTime().AddHours(5)
```

Comment: that won't work, because it delivers a DateTime that has DateTimeKind.Utc.

Answer (score 0):

Is [DateTimeOffset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.aspx) what you are looking for?  One of its [constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351980.aspx) takes a DateTime and an offset.

Answer (score 0):

Paulo's answer should work fine, but the [DateTimeOffset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.aspx) struct in .NET 3.5 seems built for your question.